# Laravel firstOrNew() function UPDATES existing record but doesn't save new record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

the code bellow should be updating and saving the weekly_item using the same button. The update works fine. I have manually added a record in database and its getting updated. But when it comes to saving the function not saving the data.

```
public function store(){

        $WeeklyItems = weekly_item::firstOrNew(['item_id'=>request('item_id')],
                                               ['restaurant_id'=>request('restaurant_id')],
                                               ['avil_date'=>request('avile_date')],
                                                ['start_time'=>request('start_time')]
                                               );

        
        $WeeklyItems->item_id = request('item_id');
        $WeeklyItems->restaurant_id = request('restaurant_id');
        $WeeklyItems->start_time=request('start_time');
        $WeeklyItems->end_time=request('end_time');
        $WeeklyItems->tiffin=request('tiffin-switch');
        $WeeklyItems->lunch=request('lunch-switch');
        $WeeklyItems->snacks=request('snacks-switch');
        $WeeklyItems->dinner=request('dinner-switch');
        $WeeklyItems->special=request('special-switch');
        $WeeklyItems->extend=request('extend-avil');
        $WeeklyItems->unit=request('unit');
        $WeeklyItems->quantity=request('quantity');
        $WeeklyItems->avil_date=request('avil_date');
    
        $WeeklyItems->save();

        editWeeklyItem(request('item_id'),request('restaurant_id'));

    }
```

Comment: The update works fine. But when it comes to saving the function not saving the data.
How can you update when the function cant save data?

Comment: I can't create new records but the existing ones are getting updated.

Comment: why dont you just do like create or update (laravel way)? so there's a 2 method store and update

Comment: Sure, my dear. Cause firstOrNew search for a first record that exists and else then created. You code find this register and if exists, update it. Laravel no have any problem, is your logic code. [You also have these other methods](https://laravel-news.com/firstornew-firstorcreate-firstor-updateorcreate)

Answer (score 0):

I am fed up. Tried all the inbuilt functions(firstOrNew,firstOrCreate...etc) and failed. Now I am using two different methods for create and update operations. The save operations works fine. But the update method not working. Someone please

```
public function updateWeeklyItem(){
        
        $item_id=request('item_id');
        $restaurant_id=request('restaurant_id');
        $avil_date=request('avil_date');


        weekly_item::where(function($query) use ($item_id, $restaurant_id,$avil_date){
            $query->where('item_id', $item_id)
        ->where('restaurant_id', $restaurant_id)
        >where('avil_date', $avil_date);
         })->update ([
        'start_time'=>request('start_time'),
        'end_time'=>request('end_time'),
        'tiffin-switch'=>request('tiffin-switch'),
        'lunch-switch'=>request('lunch-switch'),
        'snacks-switch'=>request('snacks-switch'),
        'dinner-switch'=>request('dinner-switch'),
        'special-switch'=>request('special-switch'),
        'extend-avil'=>request('extend-avil'),
        'unit'=>request('unit'),
        'quantity'=>request('quantity')
        ]);

        editWeeklyItem(request('item_id'),request('restaurant_id'));
    }
```